# PORTA software and Polyhedron theory

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, math-software, polyhedra, integer-programming

In [PORTA](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/PORTA/), we can enumerate tall the valid integer points within a Polyhedron using 'vint' function.

I can call traf example.ieq with no problem. However, I cannot call vint function to get integer points of my Polyhedron.

This is what I did:

1) I put all my inequalities in a file named example.ieq

2) I call the following command: vint example.ieq

However, I get this error "'valid' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I have altered the format of my .ieq file and tried many times. I still cannot make 'vint' function works in PORTA such that I can get the integer points of my Polyhedron.

I very much appreciate if anyone let me know what I am missing.

PS: I'm using Windows. Also, I added PORTA to my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to calculate all the extreme points, you should use traf. It will generate a .poi file, then you can delete all the fractional points (can be done by writing some matlab or python code) and use the traf command again to get the convex hull description.

Have you checked in your .ieq file, there should be a valid section for valid points?